# "No session ID found " - Yodlee login API

Tags: authentication, yodlee

I get this on Yodlee login API call:

> "No session ID found ".

Although I am passing correct `cobSessionToken`.

Endpoint: https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/login

I am passing input parameters in body

> {"cobSessionToken":"08062013_0:a401c173dc5440a4d1844623b85b3aa0113e8888cefade55da62fee5bfb029500ed82a272bc8c11a44f42eb55832c1eebdc5503ff06fda9bbc62b91192acd984",
> "login":"*******","password":"*******"
> }

Response:

```
{
"Error": [
{
  "errorDetail": "No session ID found "
}
  ]
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you will edit your question and provide details like, which API you are calling(with the API endpoint) and what is the request param and response you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

In login and password input parameter, I had to pass autogenerated test user credentials.
Ex-
   login : sbMem(userid)1
   password: sbMem(userid)1#123

And content-type should have x-www-form-urlencoded.